# Can MySQL do row level security or what Oracle calls virtual private databases?

Tags: mysql, security

Does MySQL have any equivalent feature to Oracle's [virtual private databases](http://www.oracle.com/technology/pub/articles/10gdba/week14_10gdba.html) in 10g. It is also known as row level security.

I prefer not to implement anything like columns and triggers. I am looking for a solution similar to Oracle's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL does not have this feature, however [PostgreSQL does](http://code.google.com/p/sepgsql/).